# Powershell how to store and ID giving back from a post method

Tags: sql, json, api, powershell, post

Okay i wrote the following code to post to an API. The API then returns back an ID that i need to store back into a database. How would i go in doing this i am so confused or is better to store it in memory? I feel that sending it back to sql will be much better. So to be clear again once i run the script i will get back a response back saying that it added what i wanted and it will give me back an ID basically tagging what was added. I need to grab that ID and send it back to a database simultaneously after it is added to the API

```
$DBServer = "xxxxx"
$DataBaseName = "xxxxxx"
$Connection = new-object system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection #Set new object to connect to sql database
$Connection.ConnectionString ="server=$DBServer;database=$databasename;trusted_connection=True" # Connection string setting for local machine database with window authentication
Write-host "Connection Information:"  -foregroundcolor yellow -backgroundcolor black
$Connection  #List connection information to screen
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand #setting object to use sql commands

############ MAIN ####################################
$SqlQuery = @"
SELECT [DeviceId]
      ,[DeviceName]
  FROM [xxx].[dbo].[xxx] 
  order by 2

"@

$Connection.open()

Write-host "Connection to the $DatabaseName DB was successful." -foregroundcolor green -backgroundcolor black
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$SqlCmd.Connection = $Connection
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$Connection.Close()

######  Will Creds be required??
#Web Client connection 
$WebClient = New-Object net.webclient
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions

#Credentials
$userName ="xxxxxxx"
$password = "xxxxxxxx"
$pair = "$($userName):$($password)"
$encodedCreds = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes($pair))
$basicAuthValue = "Basic $encodedCreds"

$Headers = @{
    Authorization = $basicAuthValue
}


#ConvertFromJson
$webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($username, $password)

foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
        #Note sure of the URL at this point..
        $URL = "https://xxxxxxxxx/xxxx/xx"
        $Endpoint = "/devices.json/$($Row[0])/xxxxxxxxx"
        $URLSvc = "$URL$Endpoint"

        #write-host $URLSvc + " - " + $($Row[1])
        ###########  TEST    ####################

        # Create JSON Hash
        $JsonTemplate = ConvertTo-Json @{  
                       "applicationName"= "xxx-$($Row[1])";
                       "applicationType"= "xxxxx";
                       "description1"= "xxxxx";
                       "description2"= "";
                       "passwordCompositionPolicyId"= "xxxxx"
}



        ## Write out for Display
        #ConvertFromJson!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        Write-Host $JsonTemplate   -foregroundcolor Red -backgroundcolor White
        $xxx = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Headers $Headers -Uri $URLSvc -Body $JsonTemplate -ContentType application/json
        Write-Host $xxx

}
```

Comment: Whether to store something in a database or memory depends on how you want to use it.

Comment: Well if i want to store in a database how would i approach this within the same script as soon as the loop ends?